# Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable on assignment

Tags: c#, resharper, ienumerable, enumeration

I get the following message in Resharper "possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable". Although I understand the reason for it, it doesn't make sense in my particular case.

If I have something like the following code:

```
if (changes == null || changes.Any())
{
    ThrowArgumentException("changes");
}

Changes = changes;
```

The message is displayed. Now I understand that `.Any()` will enumerate until needed, but an assignment shouldn't cause an enumeration. It should just copy the references. Am I correct?

Here's another example:

```
if (changes == null)
{
    ThrowArgumentException("changes");
}

Changes = changes;
IEnumerable<int> test = changes;
```

Do I have anything to worry about? Or is this Resharper's way of alerting me that I should be careful?

Comment: I think the issue is that `Changes` is not local and therefor might be iterated somewhere else after you've already done one potential "iteration"  with `Any`.  Though personally I ignore that message for `Any` since it only iterates to the first item to very if the collection is empty or not.

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with changes. If I do this: 
IEnumerable<int> t = changes;
IEnumerable<int> v = changes;

I still get the same message.

Comment: Maybe they're just not going to check if the variable you assign to every gets iterated and they just assume it might.  Either that or it's a bug.

Comment: @juharr It's *not* safe to just ignore the iteration from `Any`.  The query could be based on a database call, and performing that could take quite a while, even to just get the first item.  There are also queries that do things like ordering or grouping that need to generate the entire result set in order to get the first item.

Comment: @Servy I was talking about very specific instances when I know it isn't any of those.

Comment: Without more context, I'm not sure even a Resharper expert (which I'm not) can tell you exactly what's going on. I will point out that the `==` operator can be overloaded, so it's possible (depending on how `changes` is declared) that the expression `changes == null` would be evaluated by a user-defined method, which _could_ in turn enumerate the collection (and Resharper would have no practical way to know if it did). Likewise, if `Changes` is a property, assigning `changes` to the property calls a method (the property setter) which could in turn enumerate the collection.